# Python - key referencing max value in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working with a dictionary and would like to reference the key whose associated list has the third value equal to one (which happens to be the maximum value of the list's third value).

```
MOTOR VEHICLE THEFT [1802, 166, 0.09211986681465038]
CRIM SEXUAL ASSAULT [191, 15, 0.07853403141361257]
PUBLIC PEACE VIOLATION [211, 130, 0.6161137440758294]
NON - CRIMINAL [5, 2, 0.4]
PUBLIC INDECENCY [1, 1, 1.0]
SEX OFFENSE [161, 20, 0.12422360248447205]
GAMBLING [7, 7, 1.0]
OFFENSE INVOLVING CHILDREN [378, 41, 0.10846560846560846]
STALKING [16, 2, 0.125]
WEAPONS VIOLATION [397, 284, 0.7153652392947103]
HUMAN TRAFFICKING [1, 1, 1.0]
BATTERY [7102, 1564, 0.2202196564348071]
OTHER NARCOTIC VIOLATION [1, 1, 1.0]
```

In here, I would like to extract public indecency, gambling, human trafficking, etc.

Comment: And do you have a question?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

for python 2.X

```
for key,val in dictionary.iteritems():
    if val[2] == 1.0:
        print key
```

for python 3.X

```
for key,val in dictionary.items():
    if val[2] == 1.0:
        print(key)
```